# Can we find a primitive element that it's trace=0?

Tags: abstract-algebra

For a finite extension E/F, we can find a primitive element $\alpha $. Considering the situation that char=0, I find that the trace  $\alpha =0$ all the time. So I wonder if this is true for any finite extension,you can find a element with Tr=0?

Comment: Can you clarify the question, please. Arthur seems to think that you are asking whether every primitive element has trace zero. I think that you are asking whether there exists a primitive element of trace zero.

Comment: I would even offer a third interpretation which is similar to @JyrkiLahtonen. Namely, you know that there is a trace zero primitive element in characteristic zero and are asking about (separable?) extensions in any characteristic. However, the two primitive roots of $\mathbf{F}_4/\mathbf{F}_2$ both have trace $1$.

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_trace#Example) has a counterexample: If $F = \Bbb Q$ and $E = \Bbb Q(\sqrt d)$, then the trace of $a + b\sqrt d$ is $2a$. Since any such element with $b\neq 0$ is primitive, we get many elements with non-zero trace.